# Setting permissions to 777, resulting file is 775

Tags: ubuntu, file-permissions

I'm trying to write a string to file, and set the file's permissions to 777. The resulting file is blank and has permissions of 775. The mode mask seems to be correct, and when I check with access(), it returns 0. I can chmod the file to 777 (without using sudo). What's going on?

Running ubuntu 14.10. Hard drive is ext3/4.

```
if (argc == 1) {
    int fd = open ("sampleFile", O_CREAT , S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO);
    int writ = 0xDEADBEEF;

    if (fd != -1) {
        char str [] = "My permission should be set to 777.";
        writ = write (fd, &str, (int)strlen (str));
        //writ = access ("sampleFile", W_OK);
        close (fd);

        printf ("(%o) %s\n", writ, str);
        return 0;
    }

    else {
        printf ("Couldn't make sampleFile in pwd.\n");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. The second argument to `write()` "must include one of the following *access modes*: `O_RDONLY`, `O_WRONLY`, or `O_RDWR`". Change `O_CREAT` to `O_CREAT | O_WRONLY` to allow writing to the file.
2. The mode of the created file is modified by your `umask`. Your `umask` is probably `002`. (A `umask` of `002` prevents you from accidentally creating world-writable files.) You can use `fchmod` to change the permissions after creating it.:
   `fchmod(fd, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO)`

Comment: 1. That was careless of me. I should have read the man page more carefully.

2. I had no idea what umasks were, but after reading it up on man and calling it in my terminal, it returned "0002" as you suspected. I would never have been able to put that together; Thank you very much.